# POM entries for SLF4j. Getting ClassNotFound

Tags: pom.xml, slf4j

I HAVE MY POM entries as below

```
<dependency>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
```

But when the application comes up i get this error.

WARN  [2023-08-02 19:31:56,721] org.reflections.Reflections: could not get type for name org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout$Builder from any class loader
! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout$Builder